# Unable to install Signal from App Store on iOS

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

Each time I try to install [Signal](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/signal-private-messenger/id874139669) Application from App Store on iOS, I get the message:

> This item is currently being modified. Please try again later.

How can I install this app on my iPhone?

This issue has been there for about 2 months. There is news that Signal is blocked in my country. I have used a VPN and also I get the same problem.

Comment: We could install Signal on January 10th, some days more than two months ago. And I could install the latest update this weekend. So I doubt there is a general problem. While this information doesn't solve your problem, it may help to narrow the possible cause.

Comment: Did you ever install Signal in the past (and deleted it again)? If all else fails, ensure that you have a recent backup and use iTunes to restore the phone to factory settings.

Comment: @patrix I don't remember, but may be I have done so (installed then deleted Signal in the past).

Answer (score 1):

Either the app developer is pushing out a price/code change, the App Store servers are down, or there's a problem with the app within the App Store.

When developers make a change to the app, including price, it can takes several hours for the change to propagate through the Apple servers.  You can keep trying for a few hours and see if this clears itself.

If after 24 hours you still see the same error, you can contact the developer's support (usually from their website) and let them know.  It's not uncommon for this happen when the developer hasn't made any changes at all; there's dozens of comments about this throughout the years in the Apple developer forum.

The developer is the one losing revenue so it would be in their best interest to contact Apple about the problem and work with them to resolve it.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to mention that this issue is there for about 2 months.

Comment: Are you able to download other apps?  Is it just Signal that you can't download?

Comment: Yes, I'm able to download other apps except Signal

Comment: Then it shows the problem is not with your connection to the App Store, so that's good.  The developer needs to fix this with Apple, there's nothing you can do.  If you want to contact the developer, that's completely up to you.

Comment: The application is recently updated on: 15 Mar 2017. This problem still with me for about 2 months. So, I think the problem is on my side. However, I have already contacted the developer and waiting their reply. Also, there was news that Signal is blocked in my country. Is there any alternative way to install Signal?

Comment: @Omar If you suspect blocking: get a VPN onto your iPhone and try again

Comment: @patrix I've tried a VPN and also I get the same problem.